# Why is JWT token 'expires in' not removing the cookie from the browsers cache?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

So I've implemented JWT auth, and for testing set expiresIn 10 seconds.. So I have 2 buttons, 1 is for accessing the JWT based on provided credentials, and second one is to check if it can be fetched.. First one is working and after I try to fetch the token it works fine on the backend, and after 10 seconds if I press fetch again it shows an error that jwt is expired, which also should happen, but the token is still visible in Application->Cookies on a local host.. Is that ok or it shouldn't be there after expiration? [image]

Here is how the cookie is setup:

```
app.post('/api/auth', (req, res) => {
  const user = req.body;
  const username = user['username'];
  const password = user['password'];

  const token = jwt.sign(user, process.env.JWT_SECRET_HASH, { expiresIn: '10s' });
  res.cookie('token', token, { httpOnly: true, secure: true });
  return res.redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: Your server can clear that cookie out it it wants too

Comment: How to do that? should I be giving another parameter in jwt.sign() function?

Comment: How’s the cookie set in the first place?

Comment: @DanielA.White I've updated the question with the code for cookie

Comment: This question should not be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be fine as the JWT has expired and will be unusable, however when you set the cookie you can also give it an expiry in milliseconds using the `maxAge` option: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie

```js
res.cookie('token', token, { httpOnly: true, secure: true, maxAge: 10 * 1000 });
```

The browser will then automatically remove the cookie from its cache.

Comment: Yes that worked.. maxAge will clear the cookie from browser.. Thanks a lot